# Yii mod rewrite with CUrlManagement

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, yii, slug

Is there any possibility to get the following example:

- example.com/Itemname instead of
  example.com/index.php?r=item/index&name=Itemname

So I have to set the CUrlManagement rules dynamically, but how?
My first guess was: try to set UrlManagement rules in the controller or model, but I found a thread  which says, that it isnt possible in yii 1.x

Another way could be, to make use of a slug behavior - but I havent found a good extension so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by  extends CBaseUrlRule see the example of the car ;-)

[custom url rule](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/fr/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot set url routes from a controller dynamically, they have to be set in the config on run time. Although you can extend the CBaseUrlRule to load rules from an external source such as a database instead of hard coding them.

If you want more information I would suggest you read the Definitive Guide at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide